# Validation errors with the date field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-field-collection

I am getting a validation error while saving a node for the date/time fields while the settings and data entry are normal.
I spent more time in it and can't find the issue root cause

The fields are in field collection, please check the attached images.

[image: Validation errors]

[image: Field highlighted for an error]

[image: Field type]

Field settings
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the field's configuration from Structure > Content Types > [your content type] > Manage Fields > First Dose time > edit > field settings tab?

Chances are there is a minimum value (start date) requirement and 30-minute increment of allowed times set on the field.

Comment: @AnsonWHan, a screenshot for field settings is added.
Just note, the field in a field collection not directly in the content type

Comment: Can you update the screenshot with the "More Settings and Values" section expanded?

Comment: @AnsonWHanthe screenshot is updated now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Settings all seem correct for the field type. (A) What widget type is being used?   
I was able to input times using the popup-calendar widget type.  It may be worth trying inputting the time with seconds (ie. 23:45:00) just to see if that saves.

(B) If you enable watchdog/database logging, are there any warning or error messages being logged to the Recent Message Log when you try to save?  
(C) Is this custom content type defined in code?  If so, there may be custom form validation in place on save.